# Drupal 7 CCK fields deconstruction from $content in node.tpl.php file

Tags: view, drupal-7, cck

After a long quest, finally I got the solution for splitting $content in Drupal 7 in node.tpl.php.

Previously i was using i was using:

```
print $node->field_name['und'][0]['value'];
```

Which was giving a warning:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in include() (line 24 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drup\sites\all\themes\myCustomTheme\node.tpl.php)
```

Now I am using the function below which works fine with no errors

```
$output= field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_name');
$output = $output[0]['safe_value'];
print $output;
```

Now the problem is I have more than 50 fields on the page , I don't think it would be efficient to call field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_name') function 50 times.

Whats the alternate?
OR should I strict to the field_get_items function 
OR should I strict to the print $node->field_name['und'][0]['value']; which I heard is not good to use in Drupal 7 as und is undefined. This though solves my problem but gives irritating warnings.

Answer (score 0):

In your template you should have access to the variables that are preprocessed earlier.

Each of your field is actually a variable so you can do $field_name[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['safe_value']

To get rid of error notices, I suggest that you use the isset() function